# Change prolog versions

Tags: 14.04, apt

So I installed prolog version 7.2.3 on my Ubuntu system (v14.04) but I would like to uninstall this from my system and install prolog version 6.x

I remember using

```
sudo apt-get install swi-prolog
```

But that was just to install v7.2.3. When I tried to remove it the same way with this command:

```
sudo apt-get remove swi-prolog
```

But it seems like it didn't do anything because when I typed in:

```
prolog --version
```

or

```
swipl --version
```

These both show version 7.2.3 even though it says that apt-get successfully removed it. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Also, I should mention that I tried looking online for this but most forums/stackexchange posts said try using:

```
make uninstall
```

But when I tried to type that, it didn't work. And most other questions are using different systems of Ubuntu and Prolog.

Comment: The standard version of `swi-prolog`  for 14.04 appears to be 6.6.4, so to get 7.2.3 did you add a PPA? or install from source?

Comment: Probably, I thought I chose a stable version but it seems that I chose the developmental one instead. I followed the instructions on this site (http://www.swi-prolog.org/build/Debian.html). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
apt-get remove swi-prolog*
```

If you install prolog via apt, a lot of extra swipl packages are also installed (for example swi-prolog-nox, which is the swipl version without a GUI). By using the wildcard all these versions should be removed, too